# Table row cell values update by using row number

Tags: jquery, html

```
 $('#mytable').parent(rownum).parent().find(".one").text(name);
<table id="mytable" class="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="mytd">Name</td>
                    <td class="mytd">Age</td>
                    <td class="mytd">Gender</td>
                    <td class="mytd">Skills</td>
                    <td class="mytd">Note</td>
                </tr>
                <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
                <tr>                    
                <td class='one'><? echo $row["name"];?></td>
                <td class='two'><? echo $row["age"];?></td>
                <td class='three'><? echo $row["gender"];?></td>
                <td class='four'><? echo $row["skills"];?></td>
                <td class='five'><? echo $row["note"] ;?></td>
                <td><button id='edit' value='edit'>Edit</button></td>
                <td><button value='delete' id='delete'>Delete</button></td>                 
                </tr>
                <? } ?>
            </table>
```

I want to update the selected tr cell value by passing the rownum to the parent but its updating to all the cells of all tr's.Please help..

Comment: Please give me correct way and oblige to explain...

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
$('#mytable tr').eq(rownum).find(".one").text(name)
```